# GoogleApps - how can I import my application

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, import

I created an application on the other machine and now I want to import it on another. I'm using Eclipse. How can I do that? I tried 'Import Hosted Google Project' but list of projects was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to follow the steps outlined [here](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/existingprojects.html). It's really as simple as creating a new project (select create project from existing source) and enabling the plugin.

Comment: oh wait, I can load existing project from my disc but I want to import my project from GoogleApps server. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: You can download a running app from appengine with appcfg (see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_an_Application) but this will only contain the binaries, not the source. BTW: the "Import Hosted Google Project" is for projects where you're using Google Code for hosting your svn/git/mercurial repository.

Comment: ok, so the best way is commit my project on f.e. GitHub and download it from repository. Am I right?